# Unbalanced quotes auto-inserted in AUCTeX mode

Tags: auctex, text-editing, pairing

This seems like it should be a very basic question, but I cannot find an answer anywhere.

When writing in AUCTeX mode the auto-inserted paired quotation marks are now unbalanced. That is, when I type the double quote button, I get two backpacks and ONE single quote, rather than two backticks and two single quotes, as expected: ``' instead of the two '' after the backticks. (Sorry that looks odd...I couldn't get two backticks in two places without it converting into a code block).

Note that I do not have this problem in other modes. All other text entry modes have balanced quotes auto-inserted. And the problem under AUCTeX seems limited to quotes (I have not found any braces, parens, brackets or other pairs that are unbalanced).

This has happened in the past month, and I don't recall installing anything new that I *thought* would conflict. I have been trying to uninstall modes/packages/etc., changing my .emacs file, and other tweaks to fix the problem, or at least figure out where the problem arises. But so far, no luck.

If it helps, here are the list of minor modes running when I am editing a .tex file:

```
Enabled minor modes: Abbrev Anzu Auto-Composition Auto-Compression
Auto-Encryption Auto-Fill Auto-Insert Centered-Cursor Column-Number
Company Delete-Selection Desktop-Save Diff-Auto-Refine Diff-Hl
Electric-Indent Erc-Autojoin Erc-Button Erc-Fill Erc-Irccontrols
Erc-List Erc-Match Erc-Menu Erc-Move-To-Prompt Erc-Netsplit
Erc-Networks Erc-Noncommands Erc-Pcomplete Erc-Readonly Erc-Ring
Erc-Spelling Erc-Stamp Erc-Track Erc-Truncate File-Name-Shadow Flx-Ido
Flycheck Flyspell Font-Lock Global-Anzu Global-Auto-Revert
Global-Company Global-Diff-Hl Global-Flycheck Global-Font-Lock
Global-Hl-Line Global-Undo-Tree Ido-Ubiquitous Latex-Math Line-Number
Magit-Auto-Revert Menu-Bar Mouse-Wheel Prelude Prelude-Global
Projectile Projectile-Global Recentf Reftex Savehist Shell-Dirtrack
Show-Smartparens Show-Smartparens-Global Size-Indication Smartparens
Sublimity Tex-Pdf Tooltip Transient-Mark Undo-Tree Visual-Line
Volatile-Highlights Which-Function Whitespace Winner
```

(Geeze, that seems like too many. Maybe a topic for another question.)

Comment: In AUCTeX, backtick is the default abbrev prefix, see https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Mathematics  If you want to add quotes, AUCTeX has a special support for that, see https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Quotes  Usually you can just type `"` to get the opening double backticks, and another `"` after the word/sentence to insert the closing quotes `''`.

Comment: @giordano IIUC, that's exactly what he's doing, and he says it's not working.

Comment: OP, you can try [the bug hunter](https://github.com/Malabarba/elisp-bug-hunter). It should help you bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: @Malabarba yes, you got it. I'm typing the first double quote, which automatically creates the first two backticks, but is now giving only a single quote to close. 

I'll look into the bughunter to see if I can find anything. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I would also try to edebug `TeX-insert-quote`.

Comment: I've looked at that variable, and it *looks* fine to me, in so far as `TeX-open-quote` is the two backticks, and `TeX-close-quote' appears to be two single quotes.

Comment: Which variable?  `TeX-insert-quote` is a function `;-)`

Comment: Right, yes. Typing too fast for my own good. Looked at that function, and worked with the two variables I mentioned.